# Tuple больше всех элементов по раздельности

Tags: python, tuple

У меня в программе есть несколько переменных, каждая из которых больше 5,например:

```
a = 13
b = 10
c = 20
```

Если проверить их в выражении: `if переменная < 5`, то ответ для каждой переменной будет False, что логично.
Но, если объединить их в tuple, `abc = (a,b,c)` то при проверке `if all(abc) < 5`, вернется True.

Как, и почему это работает?

Comment: Функция `all` говорит о том, что ни один элемент iterable, что ты туда передал нельзя представить как False. В твоем случае надо использовать так `all(i < 5 for i in abc)`. Тогда будет то, что нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как Вам уже сказал sashaaero:

> Функция `all` говорит о том, что ни один элемент iterable, что ты туда передал нельзя представить как `False`.

Т.е., в Вашем случае `all([a,b,c])` вернёт результат `a != 0 and b != 0 and c != 0`, т.е. `True`. Дальше Вы сравниваете `True` и `5`

```py
>>> True < 5
True
```

Вот поэтому вам и возвращается `True`.

---

Если посмотреть [документацию по функции all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), то там приведён код того, как это работает:

> ```py
> def all(iterable):
>    for element in iterable:
>         if not element:
>             return False
>     return True
> ```

Т.е., опять-таки, как Вам сказал sashaaero, Вам необходимо передавать в `all` множество результатов логических выражений: `all(i < 5 for i in [a,b,c])`, что будет эквивалентно (для `a = 13`, `b = 10`, `c = 20`) `all([False, False, False])`.